# Custom command binding in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The xaml-editor in VS keeps giving me "Invalid Markup" messg.

I added a class CustomCommands.cs, added `Windows.CommandBindings` in xaml etc,
but output error in VS is:

> [Failure] Could not find file 'c:\users\bart\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\examentest200\examentest200\CustomCommands.cs'.

While, if i check the file in explorer, it's there.

Thanks in advance

"CustomCommands.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace examentest200
{
public static class CustomCommands
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand Change = new RoutedUICommand
 (
           "Change",
        "Change",
        typeof(CustomCommands),
        new InputGestureCollection()
        {
             new KeyGesture(Key.F6, ModifierKeys.Alt)
        }
    );

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="examentest200.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:examentest200"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New"
                    Executed="NewCommand_Executed"
                    CanExecute="NewCommand_CanExecute"


                                    />
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Change"
                    Executed="ChangeCommand_Executed"
                    CanExecute="ChangeCommand_CanExecute" />


</Window.CommandBindings>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="addButton" Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="eersteListBox" DisplayMemberPath="Model" SelectedIndex="0" Background="Aquamarine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="110,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="eersteComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Make" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="239,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="eersteLabel" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=eersteListBox, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Make}" Background="CornflowerBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <Label x:Name="tweedeLabel" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=eersteListBox, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Model}" Background="CadetBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <Label x:Name="derdeLabel" DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=eersteListBox, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{Binding Path=Year}" Background="Gold"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="376,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Height="28"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="countryComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Land" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="delButton" Content="Del" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>


    <Button x:Name="changeButton" Command="local:CustomCommands.Change" Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>



    <TextBox x:Name="eersteTextBox" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="376,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tweedeTextBox" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="376,220,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="derdeTextBox" Background="LightCyan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="376,254,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="vierdeTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="376,287,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you see this file in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Have you built your project? The XAML designer doesn't see code that hasn't yet been compiled.

Comment: Thank you Petter!

Comment: That was it..i didnt build it yet..o..man..learned something -)

Comment: I was ..going a bit crazy about this..spent so much time on it.. But i didnt know this fact. thanks again, i should have asked this sooner.

Comment: Cool. I'll type it up as an answer so that the question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:

> [Failure] Could not find file 'c:\users\bart\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\examentest200\examentest200\CustomCommands.cs'.

...it likely indicates that `CustomCommands.cs` hasn't been compiled yet. 
The XAML designer won't see your class until the project is built.